# set a default value in a form

Tags: symfony

I would like set a value by default in my form.

I am doing this, but didn't work:

```
$builder->add('points', 'hidden', array(
            'data' => 5000));
```

any Idea

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set something by default, set it right on the model object:

```php
$model = new Model;
$model->setPoints(5000);

$form = $this->createForm('type', $model);
```

Or better yet, if it makes sense, set it right to the model's property or the constructor:

```php
class Model 
{
    private $points = 5000;

    // or
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->points = 5000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use 'empty_data' instead of 'data'

```
$builder->add('points', 'hidden', array(
        'empty_data' => 5000));
```