# Symfony2 - How to pass entity in hidden form input

Tags: symfony, doctrine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass a value in a hidden field in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939186/pass-a-value-in-a-hidden-field-in-a-form)

I know ID of entity I want to pass through hidden form input. In `newAction` I have ID, or I can get object from repository.

Entity:

```
/**
 * @var object $target
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Target")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="target_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $target;
```

FormType:

```
->add('target', 'hidden', array('property_path' => 'target.id'))
```

In `newAction` I do:

```
$target = $em->...->find($id);
$entity->setTarget($target);
```

But when I persist I get error:

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given(...)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. This is about passing entity data through hidden fields, a problem I'm also facing right now. The linked question about the basics of hidden fields has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If we are lucky the HiddenEntityType is going to make it into Symfony soon: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8293

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass a hidden ID variable to create the relationship.

If you need to configure default values, you should do this to the entity before you pass it to the form.

```
$target = $em->...->find($id);

$entity = new MyEntity;
$entity->setTarget($target);

$this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $entity);
```

Then your form won't ever need to worry about the target, it's already set on your new entity if you choose to create it.

Comment: If I do so I get: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'target_id' cannot be null`

Comment: Could you paste your full controller action? Are you posting to a different action?

Comment: Just simply:

    `$entity = new Comment();`
    `$entity->setTarget($target);`
    `$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $entity);`
    `$form->createView()`

In my MyFormType there only left fields that are editable.

Comment: If I'm not wrong it's what Data Transformers are doing, am I right? : ) But it's so impossibly spinning in circles...

Comment: You could use a Data Transformer, but why bother when you can just post to the same URL that already has your Target ID. Your action code doesn't bind nor persist any data, so I can only assume you're posting to another action, could you update your original post with the details.

Comment: Yes - you were right, I don't know actually why I was using two different controller actions...